# How to use .setTimeZone(String) in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone, google-calendar-api, dst

I've made a scrip to transfer all school classes to calendar using Google Apps Script, but i have a problem with DST.
I found

```
.setTimeZone(string)
```

in Google documentations but could not get it to work.
Any help?

```
function makeCalendar(name, begin, end, calendar, recurrence) {
    var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar).createEventSeries(
        name,
        begin,
        end,
        recurrence.setTimeZone("Europe/Belgrade")
    );  
}
```

This should have changed time zone of the event but it's stuck at UTC, I can manually edit, but can not change it trough code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling the `.setTimeZone("Europe/Belgrade")` on the `reoccurance` variable, not on the `CalendarApp.createEventSeries()` chain.

```
function makeCalendar(name, begin, end, calendar, recurrence) {
    var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar).createEventSeries(
        name,
        begin,
        end,
        recurrence
    ).setTimeZone("Europe/Belgrade");  //Call on chain, not on reoccurence.
}
```

Comment: It is recurrence rule

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with this for some time and I think that changing calendar time zone did it, now it works but I am not sure why

I don't know will this work for you but i just did

```
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar).setTimeZone(string)
```

Comment: Is that not what I posted as an answer? The timezones should obviously match up.

Comment: No, you said that i needed to add that on the end of an event, that's not correct, first it gives an error, second the event is not a problem, the while calendar is, but still thanks for trying

Comment: Can you update your answer with code so future users have a concrete answer?